# Creating a polygon plane with different sections / components

Tags: uv, geometry

I'm trying to build a polygon plane exactely as [in this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rqkSebnRhZE) at 5:28, but in Blender, not Maya.

I haven't found any convinient way to do that. I select the edges and extrude it, but I don't think that's a good way.

Could somebody suggest me an efficient way to do that?

Thank you very much!

Comment: do you mean several successive extrusions? you can do one extrusion the repeat the operation with shift R for example.

Comment: Create the plane, Edit Mode.. 'W' menu > Subdivide?

Comment: @moonboots Thank you, I would only like to subdivide in "one direction". For example, my 2x2 plane should become a 2x4 plane.

Comment: you can use ctrl R to create new edge loops, or select an edge loop and ctrl B to create bevels, each time use + or - to add or subtract the number of edge loops... there are many ways of doing it... you can also do as they do in the video, duplicate and snap

Comment: perhaps what you want is to keep squares?

Comment: ...another way, in Edit Edge Mode, Ctrl-Alt select an edge (which will select the ring of parallel edges) and Ctrl-E 'Edge' menu > subdivide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you want the extrude part to be strict squares. Here are some ways to do it (among others):

**1)**

- Create a plane and create an edge loop in its middle with a <kbd>ctrl</kbd> <kbd>R</kbd>.
- Scale your plane on the same axis, for example 3 times (<kbd>S</kbd> <kbd>Y</kbd> <kbd>3</kbd>).
- <kbd>ctrl</kbd> <kbd>R</kbd>and <kbd>+</kbd> to create as many edge loops as necessary on the orthogonal axis.

[image]

**2)**

- Create a plane and Subdivide it for example 5 times (use the parameters on the bottom of the left menu).
- Delete a part of the plane so that you have the length you want.

[image]

**3)**

- Create a plane, subdivide it, enable the *Snap* option and its options.
- Duplicate the first subdivided plane as many time as you want, the *Snap* option allows you to stick to the previous copy and to merge the vertices.

[image]

**4)**

- Subdivide a plane
- Add an *Array* modifier and choose the *Count* you want
- Apply the modifier in Object mode

[image]